# Find max value from multiple columns and return cell value from adjacent column - Excel

Tags: excel, max, vlookup, vba

I need help finding a way in excel to identify the max value from multiple columns and return the value in the adjacent column.

Using the table below as an example, let's say I want to simultaneously search columns A and C for the max value (89). Once the max value is identified, I would like excel to return the value in the adjacent column and cell (6) to column E. In reality, I need to find the max and adjacent value from eight columns.

```
    A     B     C     D     E
1   65    8     36    15    6
2   24    17    89    6
3   11    20    58    13        
4   42    5     29    11
```

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Comment: can the max number to be found every have duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the max number does not duplicate you can safely use this formula:

```
=INDEX($A:$D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$D$4)/((MOD(COLUMN(A1:D4),2)=1)*($A$1:$D$4=AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$1:$D$4/(MOD(COLUMN(A1:D4),2)=1),1))),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$D$4)/((MOD(COLUMN(A1:D4),2)=1)*($A$1:$D$4=AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$1:$D$4/(MOD(COLUMN(A1:D4),2)=1),1))),1)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: I won't say I **understand** the formula, but (a) I'm certainly impressed by it, and (b) I am sure it will be correct.

Comment: Why response was more like: `How in God's name did you come up with that formula!?`

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for the reply! That formula worked for the example, but does not appear to work for my data set. My data is spread over columns C3 through R6. Data to find MAX are in odd columns (C, E, G, etc.) and the adjacent cells are even columns (D, F, H, etc.). 

I tried this: 
=INDEX($C:$R,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$3:$R$6)/((MOD(COLUMN(C3:R6),2)=1)*($C$3:$R$6=AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$3:$R$6/(MOD(COLUMN(C3:R6),2)=1),1))),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($C$3:$R$6)/((MOD(COLUMN(C3:R6),2)=1)*($C$3:$R$6=AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$3:$R$6/(MOD(COLUMN(C3:R6),2)=1),1))),1)+1)

Where am I wrong?

Comment: It is hard to tell without your actual data why it is not working. @KGHicks  It obviously works for the test dataset.

Comment: Scott, you rock! That crazy nested aggregate formula you laid down does the trick! After removing the first two columns of my data set it worked great. Looks like the data has to start in column A for it to track proper. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah yes,  The first range must start at column A and include all the columns you desire.  All the others, the ones that point to the data can start anywhere you want as long as it is included in the first.  So if you use C3:R6 you would change the first reference to A:R.  @KGHicks  Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.